# Сделать редирект с куками

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, requests

У меня есть следующий код:

```
s = requests.session()
post = s.post("url", json={"items":[{'quantity':'1','id':'32529365401737',"properties":{"name":"name"}}]})
print(post.cookies)
```

В выводе у меня есть сборка куков. Мне нужно этот куки подставить в браузер и перейти на нужную страницу. Возможно есть какой нибудь способ сделать редирект что б подставить куки?

Comment: только если прогнать через самодельное прокси

Comment: @eri есть какие то примеры как это кодом сделать?